# Pipes data is not correct into pcap

Tags: python-3.x, linux, processing

Estoy haciendo un programa que recibe datos desde un dispositivo ubertooth-one, que sirve para capturar paquetes bluetooth.

Este tiene la opcion de guardar la informacion en un fichero pcap.Cuando lo ejecuto desde python el fichero no es detectador, por ejemplo por wireshark,u otro programa.

Sin embargo si ejecuto directamente el comando si funciona y esta todo correcto.

```
FIFO = '/home/k1k4ss0/Escritorio/aaa.pcap'
COMANDO = 'ubertooth-rx -q'
def ejecutarComando():
  global terminal 
  # terminal = os.popen("{} {} ".format(COMANDO,FIFO))
  terminal = os.popen('gnome-terminal -- bash -c "{} {}"'.format(COMANDO,FIFO))

def main () :
  try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
  except:
    print("el fichero {} ya existe, vamos a intentarlo de nuevo".format(FIFO))
    try:
      os.remove(FIFO) 
      os.mkfifo(FIFO)
    except:
      print("Ha habido un error al crear el fichero /tmp/pipe, no se ha podido solucionar internamente")
      exit(0)
  lector = multiprocessing.Process(target=ejecutarComando,args=())
  lector.start()
```

Como se puede ver he intentado a con pipes, subprocess y threads para ejecutar una nueva terminal. En todos los casos no funciona.

Comment: Esto es Stack Overflow **en Español** Podrías traducir tu pregunta al español por favor? Así mejorarás considerablemente tus chances de obtener respuestas y no te cierran la pregunta.

Comment: oh, perdona, si claro dame un momento

Comment: No hay problema, todos nos equivocamos c:

Comment: jajaj bueno, aun asi lo puse en castellano, la pregunta va mas orientada a si unix como sistema hace cosas raras segun como accedas a este tipo de ficheros ..